# What does this solidity smart contract function mean?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

We are trying to modify a solidity smart contract code for ourselves but couldn't figure out what this block does.

```
function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
    // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
    // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
    // for accounts without code, i.e. keccak256('')
    bytes32 codehash;
    bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
    assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
    return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
}
```

Can you please help us out?Here is the full source code of the contract

https://bscscan.com/address/0x1CCC22CC1658ea8581aDcE07E273c3c92B6065d0#code

Comment: Please format the code portion of your question to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

The `extcodehash` opcode (introduced in [EIP-1052](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1052.md)) returns a hash of the address bytecode (instead of the actual bytecode).

Hash of `0x0` is stored in the `accountHash` value. So if the `extcodehash` returns the `0xc5d2...` value, it means it's an EOA (stands for "externally owned address", simply - an address without a contract).

Also, `extcodehash` of a never used address address is `0x0`. The definition of "never used" is in the [EIP-161](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-161.md) linked from the 1052.

---

So the `isContract()` function returns `true`, if **both** conditions are met:

1. The address holds a non-zero bytecode, i.e. it's a smart contract (`codehash != accountHash`).

   AND
2. The address has been used by a state-changing operation. (`codehash != 0x0`). Which is a redundant condition, because contract deployment is always a state-changing operation.